# Cannot get the browser to redirect after login in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session-variables, ejs

So I am making a Node.js web app in which I am logging the user in after interfacing with a database. I am using express js and tedious for the app and database part. So while the interface with the database is perfect and I am also able to set session variables I am unable to redirect the user. My web app is a one page app which is supposed to reload after logging in which is not happening. I am using ejs as my templating engine. On clicking login button nothing happens and the address bar shows http://localhost:1337/? instead of http://localhost:1337/ .Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

app.js - only a subpart

```
....
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var login = require('./routes/login.js');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/login', login);
....
```

login.js - complete file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
/* Make a user login */
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
   var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
   var config = {
        /* configuration options */
    };
    var connection = new Connection(config);
    connection.on('connect', function (err) {
        // If no error, then good to proceed.  
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        executeStatement();
    });
    var Request = require('tedious').Request;
    var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
    function executeStatement() {
        sql = "SELECT * from Table WHERE Email = '" + req.body.email + "' and password= '" + req.body.password + "';";
        console.log(sql);
        request = new Request(sql, function (err , rowCount) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
        request.on('row', function (columns) {
            columns.forEach(function (column) {
                console.log(column.metadata.colName + ":" + column.value)
                if (column.metadata.colName == "Email") {
                    req.session.email = column.value;
                    console.log(req.session.email);
                }
                else if (column.metadata.colName == "Name") {
                    req.session.name = column.value;
                    console.log(req.session.name);
                }
                else if (column.metadata.colName == "phoneNumber") {
                    req.session.phonenumber = column.value;
                    console.log(req.session.phonenumber);
                }
                else if (column.metadata.colName == "Address1") {
                    req.session.address1 = column.value;
                    console.log(req.session.address1);
                }
                else if (column.metadata.colName == "Address2") {
                    req.session.address2 = column.value;
                    console.log(req.session.address2);
                }
                else {
                    //Do Nothing - Just placeholder
                }
            });
        });
        request.on('doneProc' , function (rowCount, more, returnStatus, rows) {
            if (rowCount == 1) {
                res.redirect('/');//This doesnt redirect!
            }
            else {
                res.send("Loging Unsuccesful!");
            }
        });
        connection.execSql(request);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

index.ejs - complete file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% if(loggedin == 'true') {%>
        You are logged in! <br>
        Your details are:
        <%= email %><br>
        <%= name %><br>
        <%= phonenumber %><br>
        <%= address1 %><br>
        <%= address2 %><br>
        <button onclick="logout()">Logout </button>
    <% } else { %>
    <form>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password">
        <button type="submit" onclick="login()">Login</button>
    </form>
    <% } %>
    <form>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="sname">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="semail">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="spassword">
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="sphonenumber">
        <label>Address 1</label>
        <input type="text" id="saddress1">
        <label>Address 2</label>
        <input type="text" id="saddress2">
        <button type="submit" onclick="signup()">Signup</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/indx.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some particularities in your code

```
request.on('doneProc' , function (rowCount, more, returnStatus, rows) {
        if (rowCount == 1) {
            //res is NOT defined!
            res.redirect('/');//This doesnt redirect!
        }
        else {
            //res is NOT defined!
            res.send("Loging Unsuccesful!");
        }
    });
```

So, that's not the way for make a redirection. You must to redirect from the client side to (for example) the url: yourapp/yourpath, when yourpath is the path that you'll create a route in your node/express application:

```
app.get('/yourpath', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/')
});
```

Comment: So are you saying that the redirection should be both from the server and the client side? If say I am using ajax to interact with my node.js file then the url should be : 'myappname/mypath' as well as there should be a redirection in my node.js code? Thanks again for all the help! I am new at node.js so all this might seem silly.